# Use foreach inside string concatenation

Tags: php

Is it possible, to use `foreach` inside a string concatenation?

Like the following:

```
return  '<td>'.
            '<div class="form-group">'.
                '<select class="form-control">'.
                   /*This*/ foreach($values as $v){return .'<option>'.$v.'</option>'.;}
                '</div>'.
            '</div>'.
        '</td>';
```

I would like to do that all together, without even creating a variable.

Comment: `foreach` isn't a function, so i'm not sure the return statement has any meaning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. But you can be smarter:

```
...
implode("",array_map(function($v) {return "<option>".$v."</option>"},$values)).
...
```

Comment: What if `values` is empty ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Fixed to better handle that case.

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, what if I would like to check if `$v==$n`, and if it is it will concatenate selected to it? I've tried `return '<option'.($v==$n ? ' selected>':'>').$v.'</option>';`, but with no success.

Comment: You will need to pass `$n` into the function, like so: `function($v) use ($n) {return ...}`

Comment: It's running smoothly now, you rock!

Answer (score 4):

You can create your string first, and then add it to your final string.

```
$text = "";
foreach($values as $v)
{
  $text .= '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
}

return  '<td>'.
            '<div class="form-group">'.
                '<select class="form-control">'.
                   $text .
                '</div>'.
            '</div>'.
        '</td>';
```